# React + Redux + Immutable - how deep should immutable objects go?

Tags: reactjs, redux, immutable.js

I have a brand new project using React, Redux, and Immutable. I create my state that is a heavily nested Immutable Map.  At what point, if any, should I call toJS on it as I pass it's parts down into the child component's props?

I think it makes sense to keep it always one of the Immutable classes (esp in a new project), and I really like the getIn functionality.

Downside, it's not clear if an object deep inside a presentation component is an Immutable class or a plain JS Object.

Comment: Child components can use the immutable interface too. `this.props.obj.get('foo')` rather than `this.props.obj.foo`.

Answer (score 6):

I recommend keeping it as an Immutable all the way down.

If you ever call toJS on a piece of your Immutable state prior to passing it as a prop to a child component, you'll lose the benefit of that child component being able to do a simple reference check on that prop in its shouldComponentUpdate. See the [advanced performance section of the React docs](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/advanced-performance.html#immutable-js-to-the-rescue) for more info.

Is there a reason you ever want to call toJS? Ultimately, you're just going to be accessing primitive values for your UI eventually anyway, so it's easy enough to access them with get/getIn. And as a bonus, those Immutable types come with some handy methods.

As for the downside you mention, if you use [react-immutable-proptypes](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-immutable-proptypes) it makes it easy to see/enforce what each component expects. And if you make the decision to go Immutable all the way down, there's nothing to remember anyway.

Comment: ahh...yes...the proptypes.  excellent point!  thanks for the answer!